# Refresh Excel 2007 Web Service Reference

Tags: web-services, excel, vba, wsdl, excel-2007

I have consumed a web service (WSDL) within Excel 2007, using the Web Service References Tool 2.0.  I am able to call the web service and make successful requests.

The WSDL has changed (a new service has been added/parameters changed).  How do I refresh the web service reference in Excel to take account of the changes?  The only way I can see at the moment is removing and adding back in again?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your webservice url using its url property. try below code.

```
Dim CallWebService As New WebRef.WMS_WS
CallWebService.Url = myNewURL
```

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't address the issue. His WSDL has a change to params, not a change in URL.